# Why doesn't the constructor property show up in for/in loop or Object.keys but works with getOwnPropertyNames?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, prototypal-inheritance

So here's the code:

```
function foo() {};

let obj = new foo();

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)); //  []
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
//  [ 'constructor' ]
```

We create and instance of foo on line 3. On line 5, we output the own properties of instance obj which outputs and empty array. On line 6, we output the properties on the prototype of instance obj which displays an array containing the constructor property.

However, when I try to check for the constructor property using Object.keys or for/in loop, it doesn't show up. Why?

```
function foo() {};

let obj = new foo();

console.log(Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));   //  []

for (let key in Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: the TL;DR is - that's by design

Comment: Because the constructor is not an [enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) property.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I was thinking the same as most of the built in properties are not enumerable. 

But the doubt that remains is why does the constructor property show up in getOwnPropertyNames method then ?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen my bad. I checked the description of getOwnPropertyNames on mdn. This method in particular iterates over both enumerable and non - enumerable properties. Thank you for helping!!